# reloading .profile on FreeBSD causes error

Tags: shell, path, freebsd

I have installed Google's Go language on FreeBSD 8.1, added the path to the compiler/interpreter to my PATH in .profile and now am trying to reload it.

```
$ . ~/.profile
```

And here is what i get:

```
/usr/local/bin/.: Permission denied.
```

I also tried to use `source` instead of `.`, but that gives an error per line of the file, like `HOME=/root: Command not found.`

What can I do about it? And is this the right place to ask such questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the right way to extend the user's path is to edit user's shell configuration file. The default shell in FreeBSD for regular users is tcsh, for which you can use the `~/.cshrc` configuration file.

To modify the `PATH` environment variable, create or edit .cshrc file in your home directory and put there the following example line:

`set path = (/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin $HOME/bin)`

Then run:

`$ source ~/.cshrc`

verify your setting with:

`$ echo $path
/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /home/danger/bin`

Comment: Thanks. I really forgot that my shell was not bash :).

Answer (score 0):

The default interactive shell on FreeBSD is `tcsh`. Its syntax is different from that of `sh`. It is only the latter that uses `~/.profile`.

The right way to extend the path is to modify it in the default profile in `/etc/login.conf`. Then run `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf` as root, log out and log in again.